# What could be the CLI command to hold a Kubernetes Job (Not a cronjob)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-jobs

I am writing the scripting where I want to put my job on hold and resume it after sometime in the open shift platform.

Is there any CLI command to hold a job for sometime and resume it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can suspend a job if you're running Kubernetes 1.21 or later: See [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/12/introducing-suspended-jobs/)

Comment: Fox ...Thank you for quick reply . I am unbale to figure the kubectl command to suspend a job in the above link. Could you please provide me the kubectl command so that I can place it in my script.

Comment: Most likely something like `kubectl patch jobs -n {namespace} {job-name} -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'`